# Can't create a new Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, projects-and-solutions

I have the following problem:
When I create a new project in Visual Studio, name it and hit enter I get the following dialog box:

```
Access to the path "C:\Users\Tamas\AppData\Temp\lyy03tab.2ey\Temp\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" is denied.
```

I haved changed the default location of the visual studio project, runed VS as administrator but still no result. When I navigate to the AssemblyInfo.cs file it is showed greyed out (like when you cut it). The permision set that are granted for the System,Administrators and my user are all but special permisions.

Can someone help ???

Thanks,
Tamash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you can manually create a folder in Temp. You may want to have a look at the below links. Helpful links:

- [Unable to create C# Console or C# WinForm app projects in VS2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/csharpide/thread/fd9eab1d-9695-4a78-b285-afb20265d43d)
- [The project file could not be loaded. Access to the path "path" is denied](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/617dd1af-e885-47b9-bcc1-67214d0c18)
- [MSDN: /ResetSkipPkgs (devenv.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276.aspx)

Else Try deleting the content in Temp directory. Try disabling antivirus if installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in the past where a virus may have marked a folder or file as "Hidden".  Check to be sure that all folders are not hidden and that all files are not hidden.  You can do this by right clicking and going into that folder's or file's Properties.

Comment: Indeed I believe that is a virus. But how can I get rid of it? I have Avira antivirus and when I run a full scan it comes up empty.

Comment: Things like that sometimes are hard to fix when antivirus doesn't find it.  I would say that your best bet is to try a different antivirus software to see if that one would catch it.  I know AVG has a free version that works well.